# Optimizing digit <= 2 algorithm (similar to Project Euler 303)

Tags: java, algorithm, optimization

I'm creating a program to solve [Project Euler Problem 303](http://projecteuler.net/problem=303)
My method to find  `f(n)` is barely short of brute force:

```
static BigInteger findFn(int n){
    Long Fn = new Long(n); 
    String test = Fn.toString();
    Long multiplier = new Long("1"); 
    long counter = 0;
    boolean done = false; 
    BigInteger fn = new BigInteger("0");
    while(!done){
        counter = 0; 
        BigInteger tempOne = new BigInteger(multiplier.toString());
        BigInteger tempTwo = new BigInteger(Fn.toString());
        BigInteger product = tempOne.multiply(tempTwo);
        test = product.toString();
        for(int i = 0; i < test.toString().length(); i++){
            if(Character.getNumericValue(test.toString().charAt(i)) <= 2){
                counter++;
            }else{
                             //Is it better to set done = true here as opposed to breaking?
                break; //breaks if it encounters any number in the multiple >2. 
            }

        }

        if(counter == test.length()){
            fn = product;
            done = true;
            break;              
        }
        multiplier++;
    }
    return fn;
}
```

It works well on most numbers, but there are a few (usually those that end in 9) that it just gets stuck on. 
I think that the BigIntegers slow it down, so firstly, is there anywhere I've used a BigInteger where it isn't necessary?
Secondly, there has to be either an alternate method or some sort of other trick to cut down on the number of loops that I haven't thought of. 
Any thoughts to give me a push in the right direction?

Thanks!!

Comment: My solution to PE 303 did indeed use a biginteger form rather extensively, but you can do it efficiently even so. It was fairly complex, but it did run quickly - not brute force. In fact though, as I look at my solution, I could have probably done it without use of a biginteger form at all since it looks like the numbers never grow too large to exceed 64 bits. Sorry I can't say more, but this is a PE problem.

Comment: You only need BigInteger to solve the solution for 9999.  Some people took a short cut of looking at the solution for 9, 99 and 999 and guessing the value for 9999. If you do this you can avoid using BigInteger.  That's what I did at first but later solved it for all values.

Comment: I used bruteforce, but 9,99 and 999 were taking a lot of time. But I did see a pattern, so i inferred 9999 aswell, Therefore after hardcoding 9999 solution, i got it well within 1 minute

Answer (score 2):

I'm thinking you could cut out 67% of your trials just by looking at the digit in the one's place in the tested number because if that doesn't go to 0, 1, or 2 then it doesn't matter what the rest go to.

Consider that if the number ends in a 1, then the number it is multiplied by must end with a 0, 1, or 2 in order for the last digit of the result to be <= 2.  So you test 1 then 2, and if those don't work then you test 10, 11, 12, then 20, 21, 22.  So if the test number ends in a 1, you've now cut down your trials by 70%.

For XXX2, the multiplier would have to end in 0, 1, 5, or 6. That removes 60%. You can continue for 3-9.

Answer (score 1):

What about trying the other way?

I have solved this problem by generating numbers that are composed of 0, 1 and 2 from smallest to bigger and looking at whom this number is the multiple of. Moreover, I have used the pattern for 9, 99, etc. (btw, you don't need BigInteger other than them. Since you will precompute them, get rid of BigInteger) but I found their values like your bruteforce method by incrementing in the multiples of interested number as pointed out before. Result popped out in around 6 seconds. If you want to see my solution, [here it is](https://github.com/ferhatelmas/algo/blob/master/euler/src/com/ferhatelmas/euler/page7/Question303.java).

Answer (score 0):

`test` is a string, so there's no need to call `toString()` on it.  Not a big improvement, but it makes the code a little cleaner.

Just off the top of my head here's an algorithm that would avoid BigInteger altogether.

```
For each multiplier
  Set carry = 0
  Set multiple = ""
  Iterate through the digits of the multiplier from right to left
    Set temp = digit * n + carry
    if (right-most digit of temp > 2) 
      break and go to next multiplier
    else
      Set carry = temp / 10                       // drop last digit and carry result
```

This basically does a long multiplication with the opportunity to break out of it as soon as a digit > 2 is found. Note that, to solve the problem, we don't actually need to get  `F(n)`, just `F(n)/n` which is the first multiplier for which the above digit iteration completes.  Then just sum the least multiplier for each `n`.

Without actually trying it out, i'm pretty sure that this will run with just `int` values.

**Update**

So I've been playing with some code, and got it to work for `1 <= n <= 100`.  Looks like the multiplier for `n = 999` > 2^31, so we need to use at least 64-bit values.  Not sure what the multiplier is yet.  My code has been running in LinqPad for over 21 minutes and has passed 3.2*10^9 with no result yet.  Of course, there could be a problem with my code.

Comment: Brute force on PE problems is usually a bad thing to do.

Comment: I've found that some numbers take it forever to compute (I couldn't even get an answer for just f(9999) before getting frustrated and deciding my algorithm desperately needed a revamp). It's helpful to know that I won't necessarily need BigInteger, though, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try keeping around the results as you go forward. You can use these to make lowerbound guesses for their multiples.

Suppose the acceptable LCM for some X is Y, with Y = RX. Then you know that Y is also a lowerbound for all {X, 2X, 3X, 4X, ... (R-1)X}.

Comment: That's an interesting idea. 
So (I'm still learning/getting an idea for good programming practices) as I understand it, to implement your method, I'll need to use a data structure to store the X and its Y. 
Then I'll need some sort of algorithm to check if the current X is a multiple of anything I've already encountered. If so, start the multiplier check at ___?_ _(I am not sure I'm understanding this properly - if I am so far, I'm confused about how to use the results of checking if X is a multiple of something already encountered)_

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if the following idea would help:

> - Let `P(N, M)` = digits of `M` base `10` are `(<= 2)` and `M` is a multiple of `N`.
> - Let `G(N)` = Some `M` such that `P(N, M)`.
> - Let `F(N)` = `M` such that `P(N, M)` and `M` is minimal.
>
>   Important observation: `F(N) <= G(N)`.
>
>   Would want `G(N)` to be "reasonable" in that it isn't gratuitously large and is easy to calculate. You might be able to caculate it effectively using `F(N')` on smaller components `N'` of `N` (digits of `N` perhaps).
>
>   Knowing `G(N)` might be extremely useful...
>     Perhaps you can work backwards with it.
>     Perhaps you can perform some sort of binary search with it.
>
>   If this technique is at all useful, I imagine the hard math would be to find `G(N)`. The rest would probably be some clever computer science technique.

Answer (score 0):

To reduce the number of iterations you may increment the trial product by 1 instead of incrementing the trial multiplier by 1. Then you check whether or not the trial product is divisible by f()'s argument. This will enable you to get to bigger values quicker because you can skip digit values 4 through 9 in the product when adding 1.

The below C code completes in under 5 minutes on a 2.4 GHz PC:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <stddef.h>
#include <time.h>

typedef unsigned uint;
typedef unsigned char uint8;
typedef unsigned long long uint64;

uint64 f(uint n, uint64* multiplier)
{
  uint8 carry, digits[20]; // 20 digits max for 64-bit values
  uint digcnt = 1, i;
  uint64 result;

  assert(n > 0);

#if 0
  // short cut:
  //
  // f(9) = 12222 = 9 * 1358
  // f(99) = 1122222222 = 99 * 11335578
  // f(999) = 111222222222222 = 999 * 111333555778
  // f(9999) = 11112222222222222222 = 9999 * 1111333355557778

  if (n == 9999)
  {
    *multiplier = 11112222222222222222ULL / 9999;
    return 11112222222222222222ULL;
  }
#endif

  memset(digits, 0, sizeof(digits));

  for (;;)
  {
    carry = 1;
    for (i = 0; carry; i++)
    {
      assert(i < sizeof(digits));
      carry += digits[i];
      digits[i] = carry % 3;
      carry /= 3;
    }
    if (i >= digcnt) digcnt = i;

    result = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < digcnt; i++)
      result = result * 10 + digits[digcnt - 1 - i];

    if (result % n == 0)
    {
      *multiplier = result / n;
      break;
    }
  }

  return result;
}

int main(void)
{
  uint i;
  uint64 sum = 0, product, multiplier;
  time_t t;
  char* p;

  for (i = 1; i <= 10000; i++)
  {
    product = f(i, &multiplier);
    printf("%s ", ((time(&t), p = ctime(&t)), p[strlen(p) - 1] = '\0', p));
    printf("f(%u) = %llu = %u * %llu\n", i, product, i, multiplier);
    sum += multiplier;
  }
  printf("%s ", ((time(&t), p = ctime(&t)), p[strlen(p) - 1] = '\0', p));
  printf("sum(f(n)/n) = %llu\n", sum);

  return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Mon Jan  9 12:18:22 2012 f(1) = 1 = 1 * 1
Mon Jan  9 12:18:22 2012 f(2) = 2 = 2 * 1
Mon Jan  9 12:18:22 2012 f(3) = 12 = 3 * 4
Mon Jan  9 12:18:22 2012 f(4) = 12 = 4 * 3
Mon Jan  9 12:18:22 2012 f(5) = 10 = 5 * 2
Mon Jan  9 12:18:22 2012 f(6) = 12 = 6 * 2
Mon Jan  9 12:18:22 2012 f(7) = 21 = 7 * 3
Mon Jan  9 12:18:22 2012 f(8) = 112 = 8 * 14
Mon Jan  9 12:18:22 2012 f(9) = 12222 = 9 * 1358
...
Mon Jan  9 12:18:39 2012 f(9998) = 111122211112 = 9998 * 11114444
Mon Jan  9 12:22:50 2012 f(9999) = 11112222222222222222 = 9999 * 1111333355557778
Mon Jan  9 12:22:50 2012 f(10000) = 10000 = 10000 * 1
Mon Jan  9 12:22:50 2012 sum(f(n)/n) = 1111981904675169
```

If you change `#if 0` to `#if 1` and enable the short cut mentioned in a comment by Peter Lawrey, it will complete in just about 1 minute.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my contribution for this interesting problem. Pardon me for using Java and BigInteger but based on my loose testing it wasn't such a blocker after all (calculating sum [1, 100] takes less than a second and sum [1, 10000] roughly 4,5mins on my 2.4 dual core). And out of those 4+ mins around 4mins are spent on f(9999). Quite a surprise.

```
import java.math.BigInteger;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        BigInteger result = BigInteger.ZERO;
        for (int i = 1; i <= 10000; ++i) {
            BigInteger r = f(BigInteger.valueOf(i));
            System.out.println("i=" + i + "  r=" + r);
            result = result.add(r.divide(BigInteger.valueOf(i)));
        }
        System.out.println("result=" + result);
    }
    // Find smallest x * value which consists only of numbers {0, 1, 2}.
    private static BigInteger f(BigInteger value) {
        BigInteger retVal = value;
        while (!check(retVal)) {
            BigInteger remainder = remainder(retVal);
            BigInteger mult = remainder.subtract(retVal.remainder(remainder))
                    .divide(value);
            retVal = retVal.add(value.multiply(mult.max(BigInteger.ONE)));
        }
        return retVal;
    }
    // Find highest remainder for given value so that value % retVal =
    // XYYYYY.. Where X > 2 and 0 <= Y <= 9.
    private static BigInteger remainder(BigInteger value) {
        BigInteger curVal = BigInteger.TEN;
        BigInteger retVal = BigInteger.TEN;
        while (value.compareTo(BigInteger.TEN) >= 0) {
            curVal = curVal.multiply(BigInteger.TEN);
            value = value.divide(BigInteger.TEN);
            if (value.remainder(BigInteger.TEN).intValue() > 2) {
                retVal = curVal;
            }
        }
        return retVal;
    }
    // Check if given value contains only 0, 1 and 2.
    private static boolean check(BigInteger value) {
        do {
            if (value.remainder(BigInteger.TEN).intValue() > 2) {
                return false;
            }
            value = value.divide(BigInteger.TEN);
        } while (value.compareTo(BigInteger.ZERO) == 1);
        return true;
    }
}
```